# Why is separating the data container fron the database container better than mounting the data volume from disk

Tags: database, docker, boot2docker

So it is very common among the docker community to separate the data container from the database container that is using this data. The most reason I have heard is that if you need to update the database, you can still access the same data from the new database container. I am struggling to understand why this is better than just mounting a volume from the disk to the database container, and if you update the container, mount the same volume into the new database container. These processes are basically the same thing. Is there any use case that I can't see?

http://www.offermann.us/2013/12/tiny-docker-pieces-loosely-joined.html

This link tries to explain the benefit but still, the same thing can happen with mounting volumes.

Comment: It's just a way of providing abstraction. Volumes are automatically deleted once containers referencing it are gone. Useful clean-up feature.

Comment: Volumes are not automatically deleted once containers referencing them are gone.

Answer (score 1):

You can `--link` to (or `attach` into) a data container, even after you've removed the database container. This decouples the lifecycle of the (linkable) data container from the lifecycle of the database container.

Comment: Thats true but my question was why we would use a data container at all? You can just use a data folder in the host file system and mount this to the database container or any other container. This also decouples the life of the database from the life of data.

Comment: Good point. If you have full control over the host, there probably is no point at all, other than that the host volume path is only declared once. But if I don't control the host, but am an end-user of a docker cloud, I probably don't get to specify the host volume path. The cloud operator might provide me with a fig-like schema for declaring my requirements, and all I get to declare is the container volume path, while the scheduler decides the host volume path.

Comment: Actually, I think I'm wrong. See cpuguy83's explanation: http://www.tech-d.net/2013/12/16/persistent-volumes-with-docker-container-as-volume-pattern/